# Knockout.js custom validation rule for logical OR for two input fields

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

How can I validate two input fields with Knockout.js? The rule is: at least one of the input fields must be filled in.

```
ko.validation.rules['OR'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        return (val || otherVal);
    },
    message: "you have to fill in at least one of the two input fields!"
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();


self.description = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.title });
self.title = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.description });
```

At the moment: on init only one of the fields are red and one is green - they should both be red on start.

https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

```
 self.title = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.description });
 self.description = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.title });
```

`title` is valid but `description` is not valid on start. when I change the code order to:

```
self.description = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.title });      
self.title = ko.observable().extend({ OR:  self.description });
```

then its the opposite.

Even the example from the KnockOut contribution doesn't work for me:
https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules

```
ko.validation.rules['requiresOneOf'] = {
  getValue: function (o) {
    return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
  },
  validator: function (val, fields) {
    var self = this;

    var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(fields, function (field) {
      var stringTrimRegEx = /^\s+|\s+$/g,
                testVal;

      var val = self.getValue(field);

      if (val === undefined || val === null) 
        return !required;

      testVal = val;
      if (typeof (val) == "string") {
        testVal = val.replace(stringTrimRegEx, '');
      }

      return ((testVal + '').length > 0);

    });

    return (anyOne != null);
  },
  message: 'One of these fields is required'

};
self.title = ko.observable();
self.description = ko.observable();


self.title.extend({requiresOneOf: [self.title, self.description]});
self.description.extend({requiresOneOf: [self.title, self.description]});
```

Comment: curious where the downvotes are coming from. is this an obvious answer, or too homework-y?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Actually it was a chicken-egg-problem.

At the moment when I gave the title or the description to the validation, they were not initialized yet. I changed my code to this and now it works:

```
//define the validation rule:
ko.validation.rules['Or'] = {
    validator: function (val, params) {
        "use strict";
        return (val !== "" && val !== undefined) || ( params.other() !== "" && params.other() !== undefined);
    },
    message: "you have to fill in at least one of the two input fields!"
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();


//apply the validation rule:
 self= this;

    self.description = ko.observable();
    self.title = ko.observable();

    self.title.extend({
        or: {
            params: {other: self.description},
            message: "Please fill at least one field!"
        }
    });

    self.description.extend({
        or: {
            params: {other: self.title},
            message: "Please fill at least one field!"
        }});
```